# Area outside of bounding box colored in reprojected wms request

Tags: geoserver, wms, style, image-mosaic

When making a wms request to a geoserver image mosaic layer in which I specify a crs that's different from the layer's native crs (i.e. reprojection occurs) I get a non white background color in the areas outside the bounding box as in the below picture:

[image: map of usa temperatures]

The blue color is the same that is set in my sld for value 0. -9999 is the nodata value.

Here is my request. The layer has a native epsg of 4269

https://mygeoserver/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&bbox=-2300000,-2200000,2700000,850000&srs=EPSG:2163&layers=climate:tmax,climate:states&styles=climate:celsius_web,&format_options=layout:provisional&width=1600&height=800&time=2017-01-14&format=image/png

Here is my style sld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>celcsius</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>celsius</Name>
      <Title>Temp C</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            <ColorMap>         
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="-9999" label="" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="#CCFFFF" quantity="-30" label="-30"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#66FFFF" quantity="-25" label="-25"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#00CCFF" quantity="-20" label="-20"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#0099CC" quantity="-15"  label="-15"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#006699" quantity="-10"  label="-10"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#003366" quantity="-5"  label="-5"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="0"   label="0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#660000" quantity="5"   label="5"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#990000" quantity="10"   label="10"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#CC0000" quantity="15"   label="15"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF0000" quantity="20"  label="20"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF6666" quantity="25"  label="25"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FFCCCC" quantity="30"  label="30"/>
            </ColorMap>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

How can I remove the blue color (make it transparent or white) outside of the bounding box?

**EDIT:** This question was closed as a duplicate, but I tried putting `&BGCOLOR=0x000000` in my request as mentioned in the linked solution and that only changes the background color inside of the extent from white to black... it doesn't change the light blue color outside of the extent which is what I need. Here's a second image to show this:

[image]

Comment: To clarify, the duplicate question was marked as an openlayers issue, but you aren't using openlayers? that is, the image you show above in the edit is what you get if you make the request directly in a browser?

Comment: Correct that I'm not using openlayers, I'm making the request directly in the browser. However, geoserver has an openlayers previewer and I tried setting the background color using it and I still get the same result. I think this is a different issue specific to reprojection. If I don't reproject I don't have the issue.